# How can I do a mod and case on the index of an .each do loop in ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, indexing, case

Here is my concept and am hoping to get some suggestions:

I have an array of contacts generated through searchlogic, such as:

contacts = Contacts.date_due_is(Date.today)

These contacts are being output via Prawn onto four postcards, with one contact in each "quadrant" -- say I, II, III, and IV.

As I loop through, I need to know which quadrant to place it.  I think the best way to do it would be to be able to do a `mod` of the index value and then `case` the text output, but don't know how to do this.

The index isn't of the contact in the entire Contacts database, but in terms of the array looping through with the each-do.

What I'd like to do would be the equivalent of this (conceptually, but can't find examples of the code):

i = contact.index (where contact.index can be 0, 1, 2, etcetera in the contacts array.

quad = mod(i/4) -- where the possible output is 0, 1, 2, or 3 (or something like that).

Case quad:

0 : then output in upper left
1 : then output in lower left
2: then output in upper right
3: then output in lower right

**Question:**

1) How could I do this in ruby on rails?

2) Is there another recommendation?

Thanks to you all!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps `Enumerable#each_with_index` is what you need for this?

http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Enumerable.html#M001511

```
contacts.each_with_index do |contact, idx|
  quad = idx%4
end
```

Comment: I'm not sure what your interaction with `Prawn` looks like but a `case` may do it, yes. `quad` should be 0,1,2 or 3.